# Working with irregularly spaced gridded netcdf data in R

Tags: r, geospatial, netcdf

I'll be working with modelled air pollution data soon. I've been given some sample data and it looks like the grid is very irregular ('brick' will throw an error about irregular grid), which makes it harder to get it into raster format.

```
    # load packages ####
    library(ncdf4)
    library(raster)
    library(rgdal)
    library(fields)
    
    # netcdf to data matrix ####
    nc_data <- nc_open('filename.nc')

    cnc_PM2_5       <- ncvar_get(nc_data, attributes(nc_data$var)$names[1])
    longitude       <- ncvar_get(nc_data, "longitude")
    latitude        <- ncvar_get(nc_data, "latitude")
    #time            <- ncvar_get(nc_data, "time")

    # plot matrix, latitude is upside down ####
    image.plot(longitude,rev(latitude), PM2_5, 
               main="PM2_5", ylab="latitude")

    # get quick shapefile for Finland (http://www.diva-gis.org/datadown)####
    finland <- readOGR("FIN_adm4.shp")
    # add map projection
    proj4string(finland) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +init=EPSG:4326")
    helsinki <- finland[finland$NAME_4=="Helsinki",]
    # add Helsinki outline to image.plot
    plot(helsinki, add=TRUE)
```

[image: Figure1: PM25 plot for Helsinki]

**How do I get this irregular data into a spatial object? (`SpatialPointsDataFrame` or `raster`)**

Reproducible example

```
    PM25 <- matrix(data=c(4.540674,3.437939,3.373072,2.335204,2.140603,2.529804,
                          4.475807,4.346074,6.42181,3.113605,2.594671,2.854138,
                          3.632539,6.097476,3.308205,5.643409,5.643409,2.140603,
                          4.151473,5.643409,2.529804,2.400071,3.827139,4.994741,
                          3.243339,3.373072,2.075737,2.400071,4.281207,3.697406,
                          2.854138,5.448809,2.075737,3.827139,3.567672,2.854138,
                          4.475807,2.983871,3.697406,5.578542,2.140603,2.20547,
                          6.22721,3.502806,5.773142,4.994741,5.254208,2.594671,
                          3.502806,3.827139,3.502806,2.400071,3.762273,2.724404,
                          3.892006,3.502806,2.724404,2.20547,4.151473,5.838009,
                          6.746144,5.059608,2.140603,2.270337,3.567672,2.140603,
                          3.437939,2.724404,2.140603,3.437939,3.308205,4.994741,
                          4.086606,2.335204,2.140603,5.578542,4.994741,2.724404,
                          3.892006,4.605541,4.281207,4.281207,2.140603,2.529804,
                          3.308205,3.892006,3.697406,3.308205,2.270337,6.097476,
                          3.308205,4.41094,5.319075,4.086606,2.854138,6.162343,
                          2.140603,3.308205,3.048738,4.02174), ncol=10, nrow=10)
    
    # latitude
    latitude <- c(60.1191177368164,60.1192321777344,60.1193504333496,
                          60.1194686889648,60.1195831298828,60.119701385498,
                          60.1198196411133,60.1199340820312,60.1200523376465,
                          60.1201667785645)
    # longitude
    longitude <- c(24.5949993133545,24.595235824585,24.5954704284668,
                          24.5957050323486,24.5959415435791,24.5961761474609,
                          24.5964126586914,24.5966472625732,24.5968818664551,
                          24.5971183776855)
    
    image.plot(longitude,latitude, PM25, main="PM2_5")
```

[image: Figure2: PM25 grid example]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Spacedman who provided [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/386628/working-with-irregularly-spaced-gridded-netcdf-data-in-r) answer:

To convert data stored as a matrix with vectors for coordinate points:

First expand the coordinates out into a full set of coordinate points:

```
latlong = expand.grid(long=longitude, lat=latitude)
```

Then add a column with your data by flattening the matrix with c(.):

```
latlong = cbind(latlong, PM25 = c(PM25))
```

giving:

```
head(latlong)
      long      lat PM25
1 24.59500 60.11912    1
2 24.59524 60.11912    2
3 24.59547 60.11912    3
4 24.59571 60.11912    4
5 24.59594 60.11912    5
6 24.59618 60.11912    6
```

Then use sp to set the coordinates:

```
coordinates(latlong)=~long+lat
```

and when plotted this should look the same as image.plot, except with points, and probably different colours:

```
spplot(latlong,"PM25")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick update, this is even easier using the `stars` package and `read_ncdf`.

```
library(stars)
AQI <- read_ncdf('filename.nc', var = c("cnc_PM2_5")
```